# Show $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x}-e^{-xw}}{x} dx = \ln{w}$ for $\operatorname{Re}({w})>0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I want to show that for $\operatorname{Re}({w})>0$, $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x}-e^{-xw}}{x} dx = \ln{w}.$$ I've tried setting the problem up as: $$\int_\gamma \frac{e^{-z}}{z} dz = 0,$$ where $\gamma$ is the path around the quadrilateral with vertices $a,b,bw,aw$ for some $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ where $0<a<b<\infty$, but I'm not sure if I am parametrizing the paths between these points correctly.

Comment: There's some way to do this with differentiation under the integral sign. Also: do you know Frullani's integral?

Comment: I didn't know it, but I see how it could be useful here. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Yeah, for real $w$ anyway, you just have to dominate the partial derivative of the integrand w.r.t. $w$ uniformly by some integrable $g(x)$. Since said derivative is $e^{-xw}$ with $w,x>0$, not too hard. For complex $w$ (real part $>0$), I'm not sure if those arguments carry over.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the integral
\begin{align}
\int_{1}^{w} e^{-x u} \, du = \left[ -\frac{1}{x} \, e^{-u} \right]_{1}^{w} = \frac{e^{-x} - e^{-w x}}{x}.
\end{align}
Now,
\begin{align}
I &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x} - e^{-w x}}{x} \, dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} \, \int_{1}^{w} e^{-x u} \, du \, dx \\
&= \int_{1}^{w} \left[ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x u} \, dx \right]  \, du = \int_{1}^{w} \frac{du}{u} = [ \ln(u) ]_{1}^{w} \\
&= \ln(w). 
\end{align}
Hence 
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x} - e^{-w x}}{x} \, dx = \ln(w).
\end{align}